# Disable sendmail component sendmail_submit queue on FreeBSD 11.0

Tags: freebsd, sendmail

I have installed freebsd 11.0 using the image and disabled the sendmail on the installation utility. Still, it is getting started in the init sequence and login takes times.

I have also tried disabling it in the **rc.conf**. However, it did not stop.
send_mail_submit queue and their is one other service which is always starting up.

Please give the method to disable it correctly for good.

Comment: Note that FreeBSD has a lot of scheduled tasks that send mail to the system administrator, so you _will_ build up a mail queue unless you then turn on and substitute some other mail system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put *all* of these in `rc.conf`. Then reboot to be sure.

```
sendmail_enable="NO" 
sendmail_submit_enable="NO"
sendmail_outbound_enable="NO"
sendmail_msp_queue_enable="NO"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enter just the following in `/etc/rc.conf` to disable all of Sendmail (equivilent to the 4 entries from the previous answer)

```
sendmail_enable="NONE"
```

Normally with Sendmail switched off it still runs a local daemon capable of accepting and delivering mail. This is a fairly important part of any system as various parts of the system (such as cron) will want to send emails. As such it's generally a mistake to fully disable Sendmail unless you are replacing it. (I'd actually like Sendmail to be removed completely and replaced with a basic LDA/SMTP client, but that's another story).

Personally I would of preferred the rc options to be YES|NO|LOCAL, with NO meaning fully off and the default being LOCAL. The fact that Sendmail still runs when it's set to NO confused me when I first came across it, and this isn't the first time I've seen questions from other users about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I useFreeBSD as a desktop, will be it required to run even then?

Comment: I would recommend leaving it on defaults. There's no real benefit to stopping the local Sendmail service. You may need to clear out the `root` mailbox every now and then though, or update aliases to have the system mail delivered to your actual email address.